# Unable to redirect to another page in AEM using request dispatcher in sling servlet via POST

Tags: java, servlets, aem, sling

I have a scenario where from one page in AEM, I need to call another AEM page in the same application and I need to pass some hidden parameters. I choose to do it via POST and below are the steps which I followed:
From page "A", I did a form submission via POST to the sling servlet and passed some parameters.
    2. In the servlet, using request dispatcher I redirected the same request and response to a different page in doPost method using the following code snippet:

```
          request.getRequestDispatcher("/content/company/en/apps/welcomepage.html").forward(request, response);
```

When I run the code, I am able to call the servlet through form submission but I am not able to redirect to a new page. I see the below error in logs:

18.10.2017 14:41:00.802 *ERROR* [127.0.0.1 [1508352060795] POST /bin/rap/welcomepage HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Exception during response processing.
javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No matching property definition: appointmentTypeId = platform001d
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.NodeDelegate.setProperty(NodeDelegate.java:522)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$35.perform(NodeImpl.java:1375)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$35.perform(NodeImpl.java:1363)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:208)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:112)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.internalSetProperty(NodeImpl.java:1363)

If I try the same code in doGet method it works fine. Also if I use response.sendRedirect("/content/company/en/apps/welcomepage.html") it works fine too. But the problem with this is it initiates it as a new request to the page and it looses all the parameters which I get from the form submission. Could someone please let me know like how can I redirect a request to a page in AEM via POST since I need to pass some hidden parameters whic should not be visible in the url ?

Comment: when you forward a post, it invokes the slingPostServlet that tries to modify that resource and fails. thats why you are getting that exception.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the way I understand your question**

1. User visits page "A"
2. User fills a form, then submits.
3. Your custom servlet handles the submitted `POST` request and calls:
   `request.getRequestDispatcher("/content/company/en/apps/welcomepage.html").forward(request, response);`
4. You get the ConstraintViolationException

**Why do you get this exception?**

Since you are using `forward` the `POST` request is forwarded to `/content/company/en/apps/welcomepage.html` that node is most likely of type `cq:Page`, which has constraints on which properties can be added. Think of it as a simple post request trying to store parameters on the `cq:Page` node.

**What can you do?**

Since I don't understand your use-case and particularly *why* you need to preserve the submit params, I cannot recommend a specific solution. However, since you don't want the parameters in the URL, here is a potential solution you can try:

1. In your servlet handler, see those hidden params to cookies on the response.
2. use `response.sendRedirect("/content/company/en/apps/welcomepage.html")`
3. On any of the components in `/content/company/en/apps/welcomepage.html`, you can get the request cookies and process them however you like. same way you wanted to process those hidden params.

Now the flow becomes:

1. User visits page "A"
2. User fills a form, then submits.
3. Your custom servlet handles the submitted `POST` request, adds your special params to cookies on the response, then calls `response.sendRedirect("/content/company/en/apps/welcomepage.html")`
4. User's browser receives a 301 response with the cookies, sets the cookies in the browser then requests "/content/company/en/apps/welcomepage.html"
5. Your components handle the request and get the params from the cookies, then retuns the appropriate response.

Comment: Thanks for your response !!

I need to capture the req params and I need to send the params to the downstream systems. I found an other article which has a similar approach:

http://suryakand-shinde.blogspot.in/2016/07/aem-form-submission-handling-post.html

I just added the ".external" selector to the html page which intercepts the POST request and send it as a GET request. However the problem is once I redirect it to a new page, the page keeps on loading again and again. I am just wondering like why I am seeing this issue ?

Comment: I'm not exactly following. Regardless, This was not in your original question. Please update your question with a clearer description, things you have tried and your end goal so I can help.